# Firebase cloud functions - How to fetch the model data

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-platform, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

I'm working on creating the API using the firebase cloud functions. That API will display all data of model 'profiles'. My code is below but it is not working. (not able to read the document 'profiles' from firebase)

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions')

const admin = require('firebase-admin')
admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase)

exports.helloWorld = functions.https.onRequest((request, response) => {
  response.send('Hello from Firebase!')
})

exports.profiles = functions.https.onRequest((request, response) => {
  return admin.database().ref('/profiles').once('value')
    .then(function (snapshot) {
      const profiles = snapshot.val()
      response.status(200).send(profiles)
    })
})
```

Comment: "it is not working" is incredibly broad. What isn't working? What did you do with this code, that didn't give the result that you expected? For example: did it fail to deploy when you run `firebase deploy`? Did it not give a result when you invoke the function? Does it give the wrong result when you invoke the function? Is there an error when you invoke the function? Be specific and concrete when describing the problem, to improve the chance that somebody can actually help you.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen thanks for the advice. I'll make the question more specific.

Answer (score 1):

The code of your Cloud Function should work (Successfully tested in my environment).

Your error is probably coming from the fact that you initialize like:

```
admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase)
```

when, since version 1.0, you should use a new syntax as follows:

```
admin.initializeApp();
```

See https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/beta-v1-diff#new_initialization_syntax_for_firebase_admin

Comment: @Renauld, I'm not getting any error, getting snapshot.val() null despite I've data in the profiles.

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
response.status(200).send(username)
```

To

```
response.status(200).send(profiles)
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are triting to send as response the whole snapshot value, wich could include not Json compatible lines

```
const profiles = [];
snapshot.forEach(function(item) {
        const item = item.val();
        profiles.push(item);
    });
response.status(200).send(profiles);
```

This way you return an array of objects, wich is more JSON standard according to REST guidelines